# How to convert a include "e+" string to long?

Tags: java

like `1.3094266712875436e+18` convert to `1309426671287543600`

i write a method like this, is there a better way?

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a = "1.3094266712875436e+18";

        System.out.println(convert(a));

    }

    private static long convert(String a) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(a.length());
        StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder(2);
        boolean isPlus = false;
        boolean countLength = false;
        int length = 0;
        for (char c : a.toCharArray()) {
            if ('.' == c) {
                countLength = true;
                continue;
            }
            if ('e' == c) {
                continue;
            }

            if ('+' == c) {
                isPlus = true;
                continue;
            }

            if (isPlus) {
                sb2.append(c);
            } else {
                sb.append(c);
                if (countLength) {
                    length++;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println(sb.toString());
        System.out.println(sb2.toString());

        long pow = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i < Integer.parseInt(sb2.toString()) - length; i++) {
            pow = pow * 10;
        }

        System.out.println(pow);

        return Long.parseLong(sb.toString()) * pow;
    }
```

print out

```
13094266712875436
18
100
1309426671287543600
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html). That will parse a decimal string precisely, and from there you can convert it to a long with `longValue()`.

```
String a = "1.3094266712875436e+18";
long value = new BigDecimal(a).longValue();
System.out.println(value);
```

Output:

```
1309426671287543600
```